# handlerbar template with backbone inside div does not render

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, handlebars.js

### **[Example fiddle set up here](http://jsfiddle.net/K9gLK/)**

I've following template that renders successfully with handlerbarjs -

```
<ul>
    {{#each models}}<li>{{attributes.subject_name}}</li>{{/each}}
</ul>
```

But with having same data passing to different template it does not render. If I try to replace `li` with `table`, it's not working.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>               
        </tr>
    </thead>        
    {{#each models}}
         <tr>
            <td>{{attributes.subject_name}}</td>            
        </tr>
   {{/each}}
</table>
```

---

Code that compiles tempalte -

```
 template: Handlebars.compile($("#subjectList").html()) ,
```

`#subjectList` is ID of parent div ( not mentioned in question )

And this is how I pass data to tempalte -

```
this.$el.html(this.template(this.collection));
```

As I inspected in DevTools I can see collection is being loaded correctly and as first template is getting rendered I think data is being passed correctly.

Comment: Show your view code where you compile the templates.

Comment: @kinakuta I've added more code and info.

Comment: as an aside, you should add a `tbody`

Comment: @Andbdrew yes.. I've added that in local code now.

Comment: Are you storing your template inside a `<div>`? Can you provide a minimal functional demo on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @muistooshort I've set up fiddle ( same as mentioned in question) here at http://jsfiddle.net/K9gLK/. Code in fiddle is reduced eliminating backbone part completely. Just handlebar template and data assignment to it. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @muistooshort and yes, template is inside `<div>`. I've not used script tag with `text/x-handlebars-template` type becuase I'll be calling `Handlebars.compile()` from backbone ( in fiddle case from domReady).

Comment: The fiddle seems to work fine so the problem is elsewhere. Never store your templates in `<div>`s, templates are almost never valid HTML so telling the browser that they are HTML is just asking for trouble. Put your templates in `<script type="text/x-handlebars">` containers.

Comment: @muistooshort ok. I'll change that. But in fiddle, variables inside `<li>` are working. But iterating over same variable inside `table` is not working. It shouldn't go to `{{else}}` block as `subjects` is having 2 items inside.

Comment: @muistooshort Oh damn you right. :D. It was obviously the problem you mentioned in previous comment. When I changed div to script tag, it's working. If you post it as answer I can accept it. Other users might also be run into same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template in your jsfiddle example:

```
{{#each subjects}}
    <li>{{subject_name}}</li>
{{/each}}

<table class="table">
    {{#each subjects}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{subject_name}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{else}}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">No Subjects Added Yet.</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

is not valid HTML. If you put that inside a `<div>` (even a hidden one), the browser will often try to rewrite it to make it valid HTML. That clean up process generally butchers your template.

You need to put your template inside something that the browser won't try to interpret. The standard solution is to use a [`<script>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html) with an appropriate content type:

```
<script id="subjectlist" type="text/x-handlebars">
    ...
</script>
```

Also, an `<li>` needs to have a [`<ul>`, `<ol>`, or `<menu>` parent](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-context) so your jsfiddle template should look more like this:

```
<script id="subjectList" type="text/x-handlebars">
    <ul>
        {{#each subjects}}
            <li>{{subject_name}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
    ...
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/kxc52/

Comment: I had filed this issue on GitHub and it's closed now. In comments I was suggested to read https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/604#issuecomment-22732756 comment from previous issue and it clearly states same thing as you did. :)